# Parsing lower levels in json file using python (foursquare API)?

Tags: python, json, parsing, foursquare

Since I've just started with python, I don't think I've grasped the concept of parsing json responses very well yet and keep running into the same issue when I try to only print out certain parts of a json file. In the code below, I'm using the foursquare checkins API endpoint to return my checkin history (omitted the auth process for brevity):

```
    from rauth import OAuth2Service
    import json
    import pprint

    fs_checkins = session.get(endpoint, params = query_params)
    fs_checkin_data = json.loads(fs_checkins.content)

    pprint.pprint(fs_checkin_data)
```

This results in a json response that looks like:

```
    {u'response': {u'checkins': {u'count': 74,
                                 u'items': [{u'photos': {u'count': 0,
                                                         u'items': []},
                                             u'posts': {u'count': 0,
                                                        u'textCount': 0},
                                             u'source': {u'name': u'foursquare for iPhone',
                                                         u'url': u'https://foursquare.com/download/#/iphone'},
                                             u'timeZoneOffset': -240,
                                             u'type': u'checkin',
                                             u'venue': {u'beenHere': {u'count': 1,
                                                                      u'marked': False},
                                                        u'canonicalUrl': u'https://foursquare.com/v/nitehawk-cinema/4da491f6593f8eec9a257e35',
                                                        u'categories': [{u'icon': {u'prefix': u'https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_',
                                                                                   u'suffix': u'.png'},
                                                                         u'id': u'4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735',
                                                                         u'name': u'Movie Theater',
                                                                         u'pluralName': u'Movie Theaters',
                                                                         u'primary': True,
                                                                         u'shortName': u'Movie Theater'}],
                                                        u'contact': {u'formattedPhone': u'(718) 384-3980',
                                                                     u'phone': u'7183843980'},
                                                        u'id': u'4da491f6593f8eec9a257e35',
                                                        u'like': False,
                                                        u'likes': {u'count': 114,
                                                                   u'groups': [{u'count': 114,
                                                                                u'items': [],
                                                                                u'type': u'others'}],
                                                                   u'summary': u'114 likes'},
                                                        u'location': {u'address': u'136 Metropolitan Ave.',
                                                                      u'cc': u'US',
                                                                      u'city': u'Brooklyn',
                                                                      u'country': u'United States',
                                                                      u'crossStreet': u'btwn Berry St. & Wythe Ave.',
                                                                      u'lat': 40.716219932353624,
                                                                      u'lng': -73.96228637176877,
                                                                      u'postalCode': u'11211',
                                                                      u'state': u'NY'},
                                                        u'name': u'Nitehawk Cinema',
                                                        u'stats': {u'checkinsCount': 11566,
                                                                   u'tipCount': 99,
                                                                   u'usersCount': 6003},
                                                        u'url': u'http://www.nitehawkcinema.com',
                                                        u'venuePage': {u'id': u'49722288'},
                                                        u'verified': True}}]}}}
```

I only want to parse out the `'canonicalUrl'` and `'name'` nested under `'venue'` and understand the structure to be like so:

```
    response
       checkins
          items
             venue
                canonicalUrl                 
                name
```

I've tried for looping through `fs_checkin_data['response']['checkins']` to append the `'items'` blob into an empty list:

```
    items = []

    for item in fs_checkin_data['response']['checkins']:
        info = {}
        info['items'] = item['items']
        items.append(info)
```

Thinking I would then be able to for loop through *that* empty list to append the `'venue'` blob into another empty list and finally be able to print out only the `'canonicalUrl'` and `'name'` (apologies for the ugly hacked-together logic as I was improvising since I don't know of another way of achieving the same result).

However, the above code resulted in this error:

```
          info['items'] = item['items']
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Which I do not understand since when I do

```
   for item in fs_checkin_data['response']['checkins']: 
       pprint.pprint(item)
```

there is no issue going through that part of the json file.

I know there has to be a better way to do this, but I cannot seem to find a simple, working solution so any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop over `items`:

```
for item in fs_checkin_data['response']['checkins']['items']:
    venue = item['venue']
    print venue['canonicalUrl'], venue['name']
```

`checkins` is still itself a dictionary with only two keys, `items` and `count`. Looping over the `checkins` dictionary iterates over the keys, so in your code `item` is set to `'count'`, then `'items'` (or vice versa). `items`, on the other hand, is a list of dictionaries, so looping over that list lets you access each individual item.

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution, I didn't realize I could simply go down another level into the json response by just adding the `['items']` list to the end of the for loop (doh!).